# How to replace a preprocess function entirely?

Tags: theming

I need to replace `template_preprocess_links` with my own preprocess function and I can't find in the documentation how to replace a preprocess function entirely. Here is my current HOOK_theme implementation:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{    
  return [
    'links' => [
      'variables' => [
        'links' => NULL,
        'raw_links' => NULL,
        'attributes' => NULL,
        'heading' => NULL
      ],
      'override preprocess functions' => TRUE
    ]
  ];
}
```

But even with `override preprocess functions` set to TRUE, the core `template_preprocess_links` is still called and pollute the output with rendered links.

How can I replace this preprocess function entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.8.x) is for new theme implementations, not altering the existing ones, and `'override preprocess functions'` can be used just from themes.
The hook you need to implement is [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/8.8.x).

This example code shows how to remove a preprocess function for a theme implementation.

```php
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  // Kill the next/previous forum topic navigation links.
  foreach ($theme_registry['forum_topic_navigation']['preprocess functions'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 'template_preprocess_forum_topic_navigation') {
      unset($theme_registry['forum_topic_navigation']['preprocess functions'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Removing all the preprocess functions would just require a line like `unset($theme_registry['forum_topic_navigation']['preprocess functions']`.

The same is true for Drupal 7. (See the example code given in [`hook_theme_registry_alter()` - Drupal 7](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7.x).)